# SSRS projects and Visual Studio versioning problems

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to edit some SSRS 2008 reports from TFS, but having all kinds of issues. I have Visual Studio 2008 installed on a VM I created for the sole purpose of editing the reports within these report server projects.

At first, I couldn't open the report projects as the project type wasn't supported.  To fix this, I installed SQL Server Express 2008 R2.  I could then open the projects but it wanted to upgrade the projects. This is unacceptable.  I determined this was due to the database being R2.  So, I installed SQL Server Express (non r2). This still doesn't work, as VS is still trying to update the project.  I've tried finding a setting within VS to see if I can pick what SSRS it is associated with, but it's not working.

Do I have to uninstall SQL Server Express 2008 R2? Or will this not work? **Can I force Visual Studio to use the 2008 instance of SSRS instead of the 2008 R2?**

Any help is appreciated. Right now I would just like to know how to get this machine working for 2008 reports.

I'll create a different VM for 2008 R2 reports, and another to support 2005 reports and then I guess another for 2012 reports when we get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem, here is what I had to do.

Completely uninstall SQL Svr 2008 R2 and all components, espeically SSRS 2008 R2. Then install SSRS 2008 (not R2).  Since I was installing the express editions, I had to look around for a bit on line to get the SSRS reporting services for Express.  Once I installed this, I could open the reports and not be prompted for an upgrade. What a pita!